# short version subsection titles for TOC using Pandoc markdown

Tags: table-of-contents, pandoc, markdown

I have a Thai document in markdown with rather long subsection titles and would like a shorter version for the Table of Contents. In Pandoc I am exporting to pdf, epub and html.

Is my best solution to use some LaTeX? If so, what? Or am I on the wrong StackExchange again? :)

Example:

##Subsection title that is very long

TOC: Subsection title

Comment: There seems to be no efficient way to include a ToC-specific label. So you can use `\subsection[Subsection title]{Subsection title that is very long}`.

Comment: IMHO this is a question about how to define a different title to be used for the ToC entry with markdown. This would be indeed off-topic. Doing the same in LaTeX depends on the class. For example `memoir` or KOMA-Script classes provide this a native feature. For the standard classes it is more tricky, because you could need something like `\subsectionmark{…}` to have the wanted running head. So we would need more information.